# Replace all characters in a String in Swift

Tags: swift, string

Just trying to do a play around with Swift String. I want to replace all the characters in a String to a blank space.

```
inputString = "This is a String"

outputString = "                "
```

How could I achieve this in swift?

Comment: Probably like with any other language: count the characters in the original string and make a new string of N space characters... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way:

```
let outputString = inputString.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^\\s]",
                          with: " ", 
                       options: .regularExpression, 
                         range: inputString.startIndex..<inputString.endIndex)
```

Answer (score 4):

One possible way:

```
outputString = String(count: inputString.characters.count, repeatedValue: (" " as Character))
```

Comment: You should replace `length` with `count`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `map` function to replace any character with another:

```
String("foo".characters.map { _ in Character(" ") })
```

Answer (score 1):

So given an input `String` of `n` chars you want another `String` of `n` blank spaces, right?

```
let inputString = "This is a String"
let outputString = String([Character](count: inputString.characters.count, repeatedValue: " "))
```